# Unable to install PyCharm "debugger speedups using cython"

Tags: software-installation, pycharm

1. Ubuntu 16.04.
2. Successfully installed PyCharm 2016.3.3.
3. When start debugging, message comes up stating `warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"/usr/bin/python3.5" "/usr/share/pycharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.3/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build`.

Fair enough.  But when I try to do this command (as others have done, apparently successfully), I get:

```
Non-zero exit code (1): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/pycharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.3/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py", line 25, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

I have no idea what is missing/how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, answering my own question, it was a non-installed package....

I had tried `apt-get install python-setuptools`, to no effect.  Then I tried `apt-get install python3-setuptools`, now it does its `cython` stuff and all is well.

Maybe you have to do *all* your install commands with `python3` instead of plain `python`.

Is there an `apt-get` to get *all* the python tools I am likely to need in developing python apps?